# Assistance creating a correct regex pattern

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to be able to select the value of the third [] in the following variable:
land[1][permit][3][permit_type]

Thus, I need to be able to change the [3] to a [4] etc.

The regex pattern I've managed to get to is:
[(?:.(?!([\d])))+$

However, that is selecting: [3][permit_type]

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.replace(/(\[\d+]\[\w+]\[)\d+/, '$14')` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jJMCo/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for that worked a treat!! Can you tell me how do to the first one also? i.e

land[1][permit][3][permit_type] - I need to select [1] to become [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use capturing groups to keep track of what you matched and then paste it back into the replacement result using backreferences:

```
.replace(/(\[\d+]\[\w+]\[)\d+/, '$14')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6jJMCo/1)

Note you may replace `\d+` and `\w+` with `[^\][]*` to match any 0+ chars but `]` and `[` if the contents may contain any kind of chars but the `[` and `]`.

```js
var s = "land[1][permit][3][permit_type]";
console.log(s.replace(/(\[\d+]\[\w+]\[)\d+/, '$14'));
```

To also replace the value inside the first brackets, you may use

```js
var s = "land[1][permit][3][permit_type]";
console.log(s.replace(/(\[)\d+(]\[\w+]\[)\d+/, '$12$24'));
```

The `$1` refers to the value captured with the first capturing group, `(\[)`, and `$2` refers to the value captured with the second capturing group, `(]\[\w+]\[)`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, perfect answer, I really appreciate your help.